# Hybris: Display Custom Promotion only in Product Cockpit

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, promotions, cockpit

I have created a custom promotion in hybris by overriding the default ProductPercentageDiscountPromotion. But I was wondering how to display the new custom promotion only and not the old original one on Product Cockpit.

I found there are two files

```
1. wizardConfig_PromotionUserRestrction.xml
2. editorArea_Category.xml
```

These files contain a property "AbstractPromotionRestriction.promotion" which has its parameter entry "excludeCreateTypes" that contains the list of Promotions to exclude eg:

```
 value="ProductBundlePromotion,ProductOneToOnePerfectPartnerPromotion..."
```

When I write the ProductPercentageDiscountPromotion name in this list and initialize the Hybris system from Admin console, then this old promotion is not visible in Product Cockpit. But I cannot initialize, since it will erase all the project data. I have to update the Hybris system to do this, but it's not working. Any ideas?

PS: I don't have authority to post this question on Hybris Forum.

Many thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updates in the cockpit xml files (like configuration for editor area, wizard, etc) are successfully applied after:

1. run an update in /hac + set the check-box for product cockpit during that;
2. reset user settings in cockpit menu.

Comment: Hello @Lena.. Thanks a lot for your answer. You saved the day!
I was updating product cockpit in HAC, but I forgot about the user settings rest in product cockpit.